# How to get unique hardware ID for SunRay thin client

Tags: opensuse, thin-client

I am currently sitting in front of a SunRay 2 thin client running a recent version of OpenSUSE. I would like to modify my `.bashrc` to make some changes to the environment depending on which particular thin client I am using, but I cannot figure out how to find any sort of information which will identify the client I am using.

Is there any way that I can get any sort of unique ID for this machine?

Less generally, I am trying to setup keycode mappings for my personal keyboard which I have attached to this machine, so a way to identify the keyboard would also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the environment variable SUN_SUNRAY_TOKEN contains `pseudo.<mac address>`, so I can latch on to that.